# how to set one decorator to more than one element in zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

in my zend form i set decarators to each element , instead of that can i set single decorater that can applicable to all.

currently ..

```
    $code = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("mealplancode");
    $code->setLabel("Code :");
    $code->setDecorators(
                         array(
                              array('ViewHelper',
                                        array('helper' => 'formText')
                            ),
                            array('HtmlTag',
                                        array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => '')
                            ),
                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label')
                            ),
                         )
                      );

    $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text("mealplanname");
    $name->setLabel("Name :");
    $name->setDecorators(
                         array(
                              array('ViewHelper',
                                        array('helper' => 'formText')
                            ),
                            array('HtmlTag',
                                        array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => '')
                            ),
                            array('Label',
                                        array('class' => 'label')
                            ),
                         )
                      );
```

i want to set decorators to both $name and $code in a single setDecorator() 
can i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form class define a decorator field to be able to apply it to any form element, e.g.:

```
public $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr')));
```

And like in your code you can set the decorator:

```
$formElement->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators);
```